# Furniture calculations

Tags: wood, engineering

I make camp furniture.  I have been using pine for quite some time, but would like to shift to hardwoods.  My questions is thus:  How do I determine the equivalent strengths between 2 boards?  For example, how does a 1" X 8" piece of red oak compare, strength and durability wise to a 2" X 8" piece of pine over the same distance?

I know how the pine holds up, I have been using it for over a decade.  I'd just like to know how to determine if going to the thinner oak is practical before I drop a lot of money on a design/material combo that isn't going to work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: By using [the sagulator](http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/).

Comment: I would float this question by the boys at the WoodWorking SE. They know this a bit better than the Home Improvement people (generally, although there is lots of overlap). I believe a similar question has already been tackled also.

Comment: There are tables for that. Locating them is off-topic.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Sagulator is for shelving or table top spans, whereas I am interested in determining the feasibility of using the smaller boards as side rails for a bed frame.  The stresses are different.  I'll check over in the woodworking area for further info.  Sorry for the incorrect tags.

Answer (score 1):

As Derrik mentioned, the [Sagulator](http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/sagulator/) is probably your best bet. The topic has been covered fairly well in [the woodworking stack exchange](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1403/what-are-some-guidelines-to-consider-when-determining-the-thickness-of-boards-to). The Sagulator is designed for static loads, e.g. shelves, whereas chairs are going to be taking dynamic loads, but the relative strengths should still apply: if you put in your yellow pine vs red oak, the ratios should apply for dynamic loads as well.